# How to pass an array of multiple media urls into Twilio message

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

To send a simple Twilio message I call

```
client.messages
  .create({
     from:     '+15555555555',
     to:       '+15555555555',
     body:     'Hello there!',
     mediaUrl: 'https://demo.twilio.com/owl.png'
   })
  .then(message => console.log(message.sid))
  .done();
```

But how can I send a message with multiple `mediaUrl` links, having those links in an **array**, which length may vary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you indicate you already have an array object (of unknown size), just pass in the array, below called arrayOfMedia. The documentation indicates the limit of array elements is 10 per request (and the total size limitation of 5MB was already mentioned).

```
 client.messages
  .create({
     from:     '+15555555555',
     to:       '+15555555555',
     body:     'Hello there!',
     mediaUrl:  arrayOfMedia
   })
  .then(message => console.log(message.sid))
  .done();
```

Answer (score 4):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you want to attach multiple images to your message, all you have to do is pass an array of images as follows:

```
var urls = ["URL_1", "URL_2", "URL_3"];
client.messages
  .create({
     from:     '+15555555555',
     to:       '+15555555555',
     body:     'Hello there!',
     mediaUrl: urls
   })
  .then(message => console.log(message.sid))
  .done();
```

Do keep in mind though that messages are limited to 5MB maximum. you can read more about how Twilio compresses images [here](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133547-Will-Twilio-automatically-resize-my-images-for-MMS-messaging-).

Comment: That is not what I asked for. Because I don't know if the array has 0, 1, 2, or more links. I need a dynamic solution. Your is hard-coded for a fixed length of array.